# NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm getting a NoReverse match error. I've read several posts about this to find the answer, but I'm not seeing a solution.

This is a simple blog webapp for displaying posts in chronological order. The error is related to the edit_post function in "views.py." My suspicion is that the error has to do with trying to store the posts.id as an argument when modifying the post. I've tried removing the post.id in the offending line below and it will load the page. The problem is that if I do that, I cannot load the page for editing specific posts after that.

I don't understand what am I missing. I've looked at a number of posts dealing with this error, and I cannot identify the problem with my specific scenario. Any help is very much appreciated.

My error:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Reverse for 'edit_posts' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' >not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_posts(?P\d+)/']

Here is the offending line in the home page, "index.html":

```
<p>
<a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_posts' posts.id %}">edit post</a>
</p>
```

Index view:

```
def index(request):
    """The home page for Blog."""
    posts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html', context)
```

My "urls.py":

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # url(r'^posts/$', views.posts, name='posts'),

    # Page for adding a new post.
    url(r'^new_post/$', views.new_post, name='new_post'),

    # Page for editing posts.
    url(r'^edit_posts(?P<posts_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_posts,
        name='edit_posts'),
]
```

edit_posts view:

```
def edit_posts(request, posts_id):
    """Edit an existing post."""
    posts = BlogPost.objects.get(id=posts_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Initial request; pre-fill form with the current entry.
        form = PostForm(instance=posts)
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = PostForm(instance=posts, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:index',
                                            args=[posts.id]))

    context = {'posts': posts, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_posts.html', context)
```

Template for the "edit_posts.html" page:

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Edit an existing post:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'blogs:edit_posts' post.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
  <button name="submit">save changes</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Where is the code for the index view that renders index.html, since that is where the error is happening?

Comment: I would have posted the traceback but I ran into errors after several attempts to do so. I'll take another stab at it if someone thinks its necessary.

Comment: Index view added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, `posts` - as the name implies - is a queryset, ie a list of BlogPost objects. That queryset doesn't have an `id` attribute; only the individual posts within that list do.

If you want to link to a specific post, you need to loop through that list, and use the `id` of each post in the loop:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<p>
<a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_posts' post.id %}">edit post</a>
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast and extreemly helpful feedback. This solved it.